# Open excel interop with impersonation in C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Is it possible to open excel interop in C# with impersonation. I want to open excel application to run under different account other than the one which C# program runs in. By default, it opens under same user account that runs C# program.

```
        MyApp = new Excel.Application();
        MyApp.Visible = false;
        MyApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Sample.xlsx");
```

Any other way to do this also welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain an impersonation context from code behind you can use some unmanaged functions from `advapi32.dll`.

- Call `LogonUser` in order to obtain a user token
- Create a `WindowsIdentity` based on the user token
- Call `Impersonate` on the windows identity. This will return an `WindowsImpersonationContext` that can be used later to `Undo` impersonation
- Call your code here.
- Undo the impersonation (`ctx.Undo();`) and release resources.

What a mess, don't you think?

Fortunately you don't have to reinvent the wheel again. Uwe Keim wrote a class that does all the above steps under the hood while maintaining reusability.

[A small C# class for impersonating a user](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User)

```
using ( new Impersonator( "username", "domainName", "password" ) )
{
   /* code that executes under the new context */
}
```

Comment: I used the code from "A small C# class for impersonating a user". However, it still opens excel application under current user and not the other user.